# Exception in stored procedure running

Tags: java, sql

I am gettinig this error while populating the tables through stored procedure. stored procedure picks data from one table and move it to other. What might be the issue? I am unable to get it.

```
In progress .. 
****ERROR****
 [2015-03-26 16:36:35.426]org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: StatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [call publish_data()]; SQL state [HY000]; error code [1366]; Incorrect decimal value: '' for column 'JOB_SUPPORTED_BY_CLIENT_BUSINESS' at row 1356; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect decimal value: '' for column 'JOB_SUPPORTED_BY_CLIENT_BUSINESS' at row 1356
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:83)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:80)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:80)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:407)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:519)
    at dao.report.list.ReportDAOImpl.publishData(ReportDAOImpl.java:460)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:198)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy74.publishData(Unknown Source)
    at proc.ActivityStartupThread.run(ActivityStartupThread.java:32)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect decimal value: '' for column 'JOB_SUPPORTED_BY_CLIENT_BUSINESS' at row 1356
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1074)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4096)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4028)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2490)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2651)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2728)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:1811)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:1725)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DelegatingStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingStatement.java:234)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DelegatingStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingStatement.java:234)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$1UpdateStatementCallback.doInStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:509)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$1UpdateStatementCallback.doInStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:507)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:396)
    ... 11 more
```

value for 'JOB_SUPPORTED_BY_CLIENT_BUSINESS' is '' (i.e. null )

Comment: Where is your code/procedure ?

Comment: Looks like the value of column 'JOB_SUPPORTED_BY_CLIENT_BUSINESS' at row 1356 is not a correct decimal value. You should check it.

Comment: value for 'JOB_SUPPORTED_BY_CLIENT_BUSINESS' is '' (i.e. null ) –

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SQL exception seems quite clear;

> Incorrect decimal value: '' for column 'JOB_SUPPORTED_BY_CLIENT_BUSINESS' at row 1356

This is not a generic SQL error, it is being thrown by the code with a RAISERROR or THROW. See the stored procedure for further details about when this error will occur.

Comment: value for 'JOB_SUPPORTED_BY_CLIENT_BUSINESS' is '' (i.e. null )